# Parámetros en CodeIgniter que contienen la barra (/)

Tags: codeigniter, url

Tengo un método en un controlador al que envío un parámetro, correspondiente al código de un artículo de mi catálogo.

El envío de ese parámetro lo hago a través de un enlace, el cual se activa pinchando en un botón, con lo cual dicho enlace contiene la siguiente ruta:

```
"SITIO/Controlador/Metodo/Parámetro_codigo_articulo"
```

El inconveniente que tengo es que el código de algunos artículos incluyen una barra, por ejemplo -> `116/P`. De este modo, al yo incluir en el código del enlace lo siguiente, `SITIO/controlador/metodo/$articulo`, la URL del enlace queda así: `SITIO/controlador/metodo/116/P`. Esto provoca que el método no interprete bien el parámetro, ya que piensa que le estoy enviando el código de artículo '116', en lugar de '116/P'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías sustituir ese carácter en la referencia del artículo por otro como `-` o `_` ya que utilizar `/` dentro de un identificador siempre te va a dar problemas de este estilo tanto a la hora de pasar parámetros a los métodos en `codeigniter` como también a la hora de referenciar un directorio a través del identificador de un artículo, por ejemplo.

También podrías convertir ese caracter a otro justo antes de pasar la referencia a la función y una vez en el controlador volver a convertirlo al inicial:

Antes de pasarlo como parámetro:

```
$referencia = "116/P";
//Convierto / en -
$referencia = str_replace("/","-",$referencia);
//Url que llama a la función
$funcUrl = "SITIO/Controlador/Metodo/".$referencia;
```

Dentro del controlador:

```
//Conversión inversa (convierto - en /)
$referencia = str_replace("-","/",$referencia);
```

Para que la respuesta se adapte mejor a tu problema concreto te recomiendo que adjuntes en la pregunta el código referente a la llamada de la función.

Comment: Hola, Hechi, muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta. El problema es que la aplicación que he hecho en codeigniter trabaja sobre una base de datos de otra aplicación, la cual lleva ya mucho tiempo usándose en la empresa, y no es posible modificar los códigos de los artículos, por temas de usabilidad. Sólo puedo leerlos y usarlos tal y como están. ¿No habría otra posibilidad de pasar el código al método evitando ese problema?

Comment: De pronto se me ocurre que a la hora de pasar el artículo al método, conviertas el carácter a otro de los que te mencionaba, y una vez en el controlador, vuelvas a hacer la conversión al carácter inicial (`/`) para poder  trabajar contra la base de datos. Es un "apaño", pero puede servir.

Comment: @antoine He actualizado la respuesta con más detalles de lo que te comento.

Comment: @Hechi me parece la mejor opción, teniendo en cuenta que el no puede reemplazar los codigos en su BD... +1!

Comment: Hola, Hechi, creo que es la mejor opción, dadas las posibilidades de maniobra con las que cuento. Al no poder modificar nada de la base de datos que leo, me tengo que adaptar a ella. Analizaré el código del artículo que tengo que pasar al método, convirtiendo la barra a otro carácter, y ya en el método actuaré a la inversa. Perdona por no haber puesto código, pero es que realmente el problema lo veía más de concepto, y poner todo el código del controlador y el método lo veía exagerado.

Comment: @antoine Me alegro de que te sirva la respuesta, no te olvides de marcarla como aceptada por si alguien más se encuentra con el mismo problema pueda ver la solución con mayor facilidad.